# Converting iCop Encrypted DAV to AVI or MP4

Tags: conversion

I work for a newspaper. Late last year there was a car chase leading to the death of a couple of people. We've recently ... persuaded ... the police involved to release the dash cam footage.

Unfortunately they are using the iCop software, and the footage they released is encrypted and can only be viewed through the shared viewer that they sent along with it.

We want to convert this to an AVI or MP4 format, so we can edit and upload to our website with the story about the accident. Does anyone have any experience working with this video format? I've Googled heavily, and I have used a multitude of other converters that work with DAV format, but unfortunately I believe the encryption on this one is causing the file to not convert properly.

Comment: Worst case scenario - you can use a screen-capture tool to record the video as it plays back in the proprietary viewer. Then convert that to a standard MP4. Let me know if you want specific steps.

Comment: That's my plan B. I'm hoping that I can find a more permanent solution, though. I'd like to be able to solve this moving forward, as well as for this particular video.

Comment: How does the file not convert properly? What does the output look like?

Comment: It won't play after conversion. The original file is encrypted, so a converter without a decryption won't work.

Comment: I guess you've tried [Dahua](http://www.bahamassecurity.com/cctvforum/forum_posts.asp?TID=441&title=dahua-avi-convert-334-dav-convert) and [ffmpeg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493613/converting-dav-to-mp4-and-ogg)?

Comment: I haven't tried Dahua (need to be logged in to see the download links there, or I'd try it) but ffmpeg has the same conversion errors as the rest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37069/discussion-between-travis-weston-and-mulvya).

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

My company software [Amped FIVE](http://ampedsoftware.com/five) supports the conversion of [hundreds of proprietary DVR formats](http://blog.ampedsoftware.com/category/cctvdvr-formats/), including the DAV. I am not sure we ever encountered an encrypted DAV, though it may be worth a try. Feel free to contact me to evaluate your file.

I fully agree with you that screen capture is the last resort.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, most converting software on the market don't support to convert DAV files, except [Dahua AVI Convert](http://www.faasoft.com/downloads/dhavi.exe).

[image]

But it only can convert DAV to AVI, not all video formats.